# Magento Issue. Can't get query to work?

Tags: jquery, magento

Hi thanks to help on here I managed to get a page to do what I wanted it to do:

You can see it here:

http://dansiop.com/guyc/our-team/

So thanks to all that helped.

My issue is that I want to use this piece of code in a Magento website and I have set it up but it isn't working.

Anyone have any ideas why it isn't working?

You can see the page that I am on about here:
http://www.dansiop.com/epbs/index.php/real-brides.html

I hope its something simple. I have tried changing $ to jQuery but that didn't do anything.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Err... what is it you're trying to do? And where is 'this piece of code'?

Comment: When you click on the first link and click on an image (http://dansiop.com/guyc/our-team/) you will see that some info appears in right pane but it doesn't work on the second link ( http://www.dansiop.com/epbs/index.php/real-brides.html) using the same code.

Comment: You have numerous Javascript Errors. Try debugging it by using a debugger like in Chrome, press f12 and look at the Console tab.

Answer (score 0):

What I see is that you have included 3 versions of jquery:

```
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.js
http://www.dansiop.co.uk/epbs/js/jquery.min.js
```

You should include it only once.

More details and possible causes: http://www.purpleivy.net/web-design/development-tips/2010/03/including-jquery-multiple-times/

Comment: Sorry I am totally crap with jQuery. I called http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js for this page: http://www.dansiop.com/epbs/index.php/brides/gowns/paloma-blanca.html so when you click on a thumb it shows in the main window. I then call this https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.js fro the script in question in this thread which i got working on a wordpress installation. Finally I called http://www.dansiop.co.uk/epbs/js/jquery.min.js to run this script on this page which fades the images from b&w to colour on hover: http://www.dansiop.com/epbs/index.php/brides.html

Comment: When I remove any of these calls to query the relevant script stops working so how can I remove them?

Comment: I recommend to include at the very beginning only this one:     http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js
and see if it works.